# What should be the action on this Low Quality Answer?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I found **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597387/3639582)** in the Low Quality queue. It looked like a *clarification* kind of *commentary answer* at first glance. Also, User had not formatted the code in it so I edited the answer. But, not being sure about whether it was a real answer or a answer seeking clarification I skipped it after editing.

Was my action right? If not, what should have been my course of action?

Also, can poor formatting /  no code be the reason for it being added to LQQ?

Comment: in my book this is nothing more than a comment asking for clarification - I would have flagged (indeed I have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know PHP or SQL, so if I saw this in the queue, I would do the same thing you did: edit and skip.

If I *did* know the subject matter and could determine that it was *indeed* just a request for additional information from the OP, I would recommend deletion.

In other words, as an ignorant reader, I can interpret this answer (whose code I don't understand) two ways:

1. "Please provide us with the output of your program."
2. "Try this code: `foo()`. Did it work?"

#1 is NAA. #2 is more subjective but we generally err on the side of non-deletion.

> Also, can poor formatting / no code be the reason for it being added to LQQ?

It should not be the only reason for a *flag*. Code formatting only takes a few seconds to fix and not all answers need code.

Comment: Exactly my point. I don't know anything about PHP syntax. But the last line *After that post output here .* confused me, so I skipped.

Comment: @ShaunakD Then you probably did the right thing. We can let somebody who knows the subject matter be the judge. [*'There is no shame in using “Skip”'.*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/2891664)